# What do you call the layout that organizes the decorative moldings and ornamental features of a building?

Tags: translation, technical, architecture

In french it's called *Modénature*.
Is there an equivalent in English ?

[image: Exemple de modénature style neoclassique]
[image: Exemple de modénature]

Comment: I think you have to mix and match 'facade/façade', 'architectural details', 'ornamental details'. You might try asking on Engineering.SE; there may be a dedicated term far from everyday English, and they do have 'architecture' and 'terminology' tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Edwin suggests in a comment, there is at lot of mix and match as seen in Google Books, e.g. *design elements, ornamental features, design features, architectural elements*, etc. However, I think your choice of the word *layout* is a good one to refer to the whole and the way the elements relate to each other. Examples from Google Books:

**facade layout**

> **Facade components** are extracted from the **facade layout** and organized as a repetitive shape tree. [Nadia Thalmann; *Intelligent
> Scene Modeling and Human-Computer Interaction*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Intelligent_Scene_Modeling_and_Human_Com/8mgyEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22facade%20layout%22%20features&pg=PA118&printsec=frontcover)

> Cornices, an important element of the **façade layout**, were built in
> various motifs such as zigzag, leaf motif, geometric pattern,
> triangular motif, inverted and flat half circle and sea shell. [Nabil
> Mohareb et al. *Cities Vocabulary*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cities_Vocabularies_The_Influences_and_F/39YWEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22facade%20layout%22&pg=PA184&printsec=frontcover)

> Rather, 70 % less glass should be understood as 70 % more freedom in
> **facade layout**. [Marcel Bilow; *International Façades*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/International_fa%C3%A7ades/zVgUXYdkTF4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22facade%20layout%22&pg=PA292&printsec=frontcover)

> Though windows disposition responds primarily to functional
> requirements the result is not random as it complies with legible
> structured guidelines of **façade layout**. [G. Salvendy and ‎W.
> Karwowski; *Advances in Human Factors and Ergonomics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Advances_in_Human_Factors_and_Ergonomics/GWC1DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22facade%20layout%22&pg=RA1-PA29&printsec=frontcover)

> While the planned second tower for the Palazzo Pubblico indicates a
> desire to impose symmetry onto the **façade layout** of the city hall,
> the completion of the Cappella di Piazza introduced sophisticated
> *all'antica* architectural sculpture onto the Campo. [Fabrizio Nevola; *Siena: Constructing the Renaissance City*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Siena/U5v2KrFA32YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20completion%20of%20the%20Cappella%20di%20Piazza%20introduced%20sophisticated%20all%27antica%20architectural%20%22&pg=PA109&printsec=frontcover)

> Therefore, in the painted restoration, the choices should increase the
> expressive possibilities of the buildings, helping to better show the
> context of the other **architectural elements of the facade layout**,
> deeply connected with the colour, and to communicate the idea of
> architecture that the building aimed to express.  [Camilla Mileto et
> al.; *Vernacular and Earthen Architecture*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Vernacular_and_Earthen_Architecture_Cons/56QzDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22facade%20layout%22%20elements&pg=PA441&printsec=frontcover)

> Fig. 2. Facade layout [*The Structural Engineer, Vol. 79. n.1*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Structural_Engineer/wPhVAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22facade%20layout%22%20lintel&dq=%22facade%20layout%22%20lintel&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two sites that offer multiple examples of how *modénature* has been translated into English:

[Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=mod%C3%A9nature)
and
[Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/mod%C3%A9nature)

From the latter link, one example is *modénature classique* --> classical ornamental treatment.

Both of those sites seem to be assembled by machine, so they aren't authoritative in any way.